# Find submatrix with sum as close to k as possible

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, matrices

What is the efficient algorithm to find a submatrix (*must be rectangle*) with a sum that is as close as possible to k? Matrix consists only of nonnegative integers. Iterating through all possible submatricies requires O(n^4). Computing the sum can be done in O(1) time using prefix sums. I've thought about a similar problem in a 1D array, but couldn't figure out how to adapt it to matrices.

**Example:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

k = 25
```

The answer is:
`[7, 8, 9]` with sum of 24

Comment: (The example seems to be species as entries increase by row as well as by column. I *guess* that in general *dynamic programming* is all that helps.)

Comment: (Solved with [a hint on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77245282).) Please give the first community you post to a fair chance to come up with helpful answers - I suggest 25 h  minimum.